# Register authentication schemes based on tenant in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4, multi-tenant, saaskit

Currently, I have created an Identity server 4 web application with external login providers with default client id and secrets.
But my goal is to register the authentication providers like Azure, Google, Facebook based on tenant.

I have used **SaasKit** multi-tenancy assembly, here I have tried **app.usepertenant()** middleware. But **UseGoogleAuthentication()** method is obsolete, so i could not achieve multi-tenant authentication using this usepertenant middleware.

Current code,

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddMicrosoftAccount(option =>
     {
        option.ClientId = "clientid";
        option.ClientSecret = "clientsecret";
        option.SaveTokens = true;
     });
```

Expected code is like below,

```
var authentication = services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

if (tenant.hasMicrosoft)
{
   authentication.AddMicrosoftAccount(option =>
   {
        option.ClientId = "clientid";
        option.ClientSecret = "clientsecret";
        option.SaveTokens = true;
   });
}

if (tenant.hasGoogle)
{
   authentication.AddGoogle(option =>
   {
        option.ClientId = "clientid";
        option.ClientSecret = "clientsecret";
        option.SaveTokens = true;
   });
}

authentication.AddCookie( options =>
 {
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0);
 });
```

Comment: Perhaps you can find an answer or a workaround in this [thread](https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit/pull/96).

Comment: @RuardvanElburg thanks for your reply, from your suggested thread we can update the already registered schemes options based on tenant while application starting. After we can't update them.

Comment: Do you want to have different ClientId/ClientSecret settings per tenant? Or do you only want to add different schemes based on the tenant?

Comment: @KirkLarkin different schemes with respective tenant's clientId/secret.

Like below,


if (tenant.hasMicrosoft)
{
   authentication.AddMicrosoftAccount(option =>
   {
        option.ClientId = "clientid";
        option.ClientSecret = "clientsecret";
        option.SaveTokens = true;
   });
}

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 3):

See the official MS docs, [Authentication providers per tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/#authentication-providers-per-tenant)

ASP.NET Core framework does not have a built-in solution for multi-tenant authentication. While it's certainly possible for customers to write one, using the built-in features, we recommend customers to look into [Orchard Core](https://www.orchardcore.net/) for this purpose.

Comment: Hi, Have you been able to find any specific multi-tenant authentication sample with orchard core? Not sure what MS implies with that statement.

Comment: I'm struggling to find the example as well. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Since authentication needs to be configured during DI registration, you will have to setup all external login providers in general during registration of authentication.

During that step, you need to add all schemes. A scheme has a fixed client-id/secret, so you need to bootstrap your IdentityServer with all external login provider credentials, that you support for all of your clients. The scheme name needs to be unique.

As an example, tenant A might have a scheme "A_microsoft", tenant B might have a scheme "B_microsoft", etc.

You can then refer to those authentication schemes, when calling methods in IdentityServer. SignIn, Challenge, SignOut etc.

Be aware, that this will require bootstrapping IdentityServer a complete set of tenants. Depending on your scenario, if tenants are updated regularly, it will also require regular restarts of the IdentityServer to be aware of new authentication schemes.

---

If that is a problem, you can probably somehow augment the registered authentication schemes during the runtime of IdentityServer, but it's not going to be easy. It might require larger custom implementations of the authentication middleware coming with AspNetCore.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to add support for multiple authenticate provider? [This Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#multiple-authentication-providers) already specified how to add multiple auth provider in config service. No need to use `app.UseXXX` anymore to config the pipeline by yourself